# Is it possible to enable Accelerated Networking for an Azure Cloud Service (Classic)

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, bandwidth

My Cloud Service (hosted in USEast) is pretty sluggish when used by customers who are not US based. I am looking for some quick win, that do not include deploying to multiple regions.

A quick google returned a document instructing I could [Optimize network throughput for Azure virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-optimize-network-bandwidth) by using [Accelerated Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-powershell).

I would like to enable this option on my Cloud Service VMs, however I am not sure this is even possible as I do not really control the VMs, the network, or even the NICs.

Has anyone successfully enabled Accelerated Networking for their Cloud Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Accelerated Networking (or Dynamic Network Acceleration) is essentially a CDN without the caching. It can be pointed at any web service, and it will provide the benefits of the Azure Network for all requests, not just requests suitable for caching.

Simply set the CDN origin to the Cloud Service's endpoint url.